# Firebase Firestore clone documents subcolletions & data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

With a structure like this:

```
.doc Name
   .colection 1
       .doc sub_doc
           .colection sub_col1
              .doc sub_doc
   .colection 2
       .doc sub_doc
```

How can I clone the document(with all of the sub collections etc) in to a new document in Firestore? Basicly creating a 1:1 copy of the document.

Is this a matter of querying the entire document first and rebuilding it from there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're looking for a solution in NodeJS, I've added it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73948157/9788634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in operation to clone a document or collection. You will have to read the document/collection through the API and write the copy through that too.

Also see:

- [Cloud Functions: How to copy Firestore Collection to a new document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691215/cloud-functions-how-to-copy-firestore-collection-to-a-new-document)
- [Firestore - Recursively Copy a Document and all it's subcollections/documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67403985/firestore-recursively-copy-a-document-and-all-its-subcollections-documents) (in Python, but with good code to start with)
- [Firestore - Creating a copy of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788184/firestore-creating-a-copy-of-a-collection) (in Swift)